# Unable to get repr for <class 'mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet'>

Tags: python, orm, mongoengine

When using mongoengine and django ORM the following exception is thrown.

```
Unable to get repr for <class 'mongoengine.queryset.queryset.QuerySet'>
```

the strange thing is that it is running on one machine without throwing this error (after installing the needed packages on both)

the model as following:

```
class Purchase(Document):
    _id = DynamicField(primary_key=True)
    customer_id = IntField()
    product_id = IntField()
    price = DynamicField()
    page = IntField()
    name = DynamicField()
```

and the exception is thrown when:

Tags.objects.all()

i looked the internet to find about this issue, and i could not find an answer.

anyone have any idea of what might cause this? (i'm guessing that differences between module versions)

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement the `__repr__` method on the class like:

```
class Purchase(Document):
    enter code here`_id = DynamicField(primary_key=True)
    customer_id = IntField()
    product_id = IntField()
    price = DynamicField()
    page = IntField()
    name = DynamicField()

    def __repr__(self):
      return 'Customer ID: ' + str(self.custmer.id)
```